# Show that $\mathbb{Z} = \langle a, b \mid a^{12} = b,\ ab = ba \rangle$ has dead end elements

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated

This exercise is taken from the book "Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist" (Office Hour 15, exercise 8):
**Exercise:** Show that the group $\mathbb{Z}$ has dead end elements with respect to the presentation $\mathbb{Z} = \langle a, b \mid a^{12} = b,\ ab = ba \rangle$. What are the possible depths of dead end elements with respect to this generating set?

**Definition** [from Bogopolski, Infinite commensurable hyperbolic groups
are bi-Lipschitz equivalent]: An element $g$ of a group $G$ is called *dead* in $G$ with respect to the finite generating set $X$ if $|gx| \leq |g|$ $\forall x \in X^{\pm 1}$. Here $|g|$ denotes the length of $g$ in the word metric with respect to $X$.

Intuitively, think of a dead end element as a dead end in a maze: no matter which direction you go, you'll be closer (or at least not farther away) from the exit (exit being the analogy for the neutral element here).

I have two questions:

1. Why does this presentation generate $\mathbb{Z}$? If you take $a = 2$ and $b = 24$, I think it does not generate $\mathbb{Z}$, since if you start from an odd number, you will only get odd numbers using $a$ and $b$.
2. Assuming $a = 1$ and $b = 12$, I think there is no dead end element: assume $g \in \mathbb{Z}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $2 \leq g \leq 11$. Suppose that $|g| = n$. Then $|gb| = n + 1$ because the shortest path to go to $gb$ is to go from $0$ to $b$, and then use the same path from $0$ to $g$, but shifted by $b$. More formally, $g$ is of the form $g = a^i$, $2 \leq i \leq 6$ or $g = ba^{-j}$, $1 \leq j \leq 5$. Then $gb = ba^i$ or $g = b^2a^{-j}$, and both can't be reduced. So my question: *is is possible that the exercise is actually impossible?*

Comment: Answering (1) the group, denote it by $G$, is $\mathbb{Z}$ because it is generated by $a$ and it is not finite. As for (2) what is a dead end element?

Comment: @freakish I see, but why is it not required to have an isomorphism? I'll edit the question to add the definition of a dead end element.

Comment: I've changed the argument to make it simplier. Anyway an epimorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is always an isomorphism if $f(1)$ is of infinite order.

Comment: @freakish Ok thanks, now I see it!

Comment: Are you sure it is the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and not just a group called $Z$ ?

Comment: @Empy2 Yes, here's a google book link that shows the exercise in question: https://books.google.ch/books?id=UV3yDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=dead+end+elements+in+Z&source=bl&ots=ilTCAovucC&sig=uWQtAOd--_E0WFMj3u95oBGpvCI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjelq6NwYjfAhVJKsAKHYSmAZYQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=dead%20end%20elements%20in%20Z&f=false

Comment: The second relation in the presentation is redundant because $a^{12}=b$ implies that $ab=ba$.

Comment: I agree that this question is wrong. The group with this presentation is the cyclic group generated by $a$, and it has no dead end elements. Clearly the identity is not dead end, and positive powers of $a$ can be made longer by multiplying by $b$, whereas negative powers can be made longer by multiplying by $b^{-1}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2820476/35400 for an example of a finite generating subset of $\mathbf{Z}$ for which the Cayley graph has a dead end.